# Replace paragraph with another

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

Here is what I'm after.

I need each one of my LIs to replace the current paragraph inside a div named "moreInfo".

So far, I've tried to give each li an ID and each additional paragraph is set to display none. 
I've setup a default paragraph and displaying that before clicking any of the tabs (LIs).

```
<ul class="sideLinks">

    <li id="sideLink1">
        <a href="" >Favorites</a>
    </li>

    <li id="sideLink2">
        <a href="">Scope</a>
    </li>

    <li id="sideLink3">
        <a href="">Concierge</a>
    </li>

    <li id="sideLink4">
        <a href="">Share</a>
    </li>

    <li id="sideLink5">
        <a href=""> Reminders</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I have setup for jQuery so far, however I get an error on the first link for some odd reason.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li#sideLink1').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#moreinfo').html($("p#favorites"));
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: where is the `#moreinfo` element?

Comment: Did you mean `$('#moreinfo').html($("a#favorites").html());`?

Comment: the #moreInfo serves as a container for all the different paragraphs.

Comment: I keep receiving a error with line 1 on jQuery

Comment: @StuartDunkeld I I have another paragraph inside #moreinfo not displayed. I want to display once <li id="sideLink1"> is clicked on and remove the one that was there before.

Answer (score 1):

You don't define `event`.  Rewrite as:

```
$("#sideLink1").click(function (event) { ...
```

Also note that you don't need the element name as part of the selector if you are using an ID.  It may even slow the selector down.

Comment: Does this become the event I need to add?
$('#moreinfo').html($("p#favorites"

Comment: @user1882810 you can use exactly the same code that you already have, just put `event` as an argument to the click callback function you create

Answer (score 0):

Missing argument. You need to pass the `event` in the function

```
$('li#sideLink1').click(
    function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#moreinfo').html($("p#favorites"));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('li#sideLink1').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#moreinfo').html($("p#favorites").html());
    });
});
```

`.html()` accepts string as an argument, not jQuery object.

Comment: Yeah, it really works... That's weird :)
But still, that's probably incorrent usege http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting might be because you aren't passing the event object to the anonymous function.

```
$('li#sideLink1').click(
    function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#moreinfo').html($("p#favorites"));
    }
);
```

That said, LI tags don't have a default action to prevent and given the provided code, the anchor tag will still have it's default action. You may want to put the click action on the anchor tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

The event argument was missing, but I don't think that completely resolves the issue. Here's a full markup and example of what I believe you're trying to accomplish.

http://jsfiddle.net/psyon001/zjQy7/

I used the anchor so if js is disabled you can add a no-js class definition to display block and the links would anchor to the text making it degrade more gracefully.

```
<style>
    #moreInfo p{display:none;}
    #moreInfo p#default{display:block;}
</style>
```

-

```
<ul class="sideLinks">
    <li>
        <a href="#favoritesDetail">Favorites</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#scopeDetail">Scope</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#conciergeDetail">Concierge</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#shareDetail">Share</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#remindersDetail">Reminders</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="moreInfo">
    <p id="default"></p>
    <p id="favoritesDetail">Favorites description...</p>
    <p id="scopeDetail">Scope description...</p>
    <p id="conciergeDetail">Concierge description...</p>
    <p id="shareDetail">Share description...</p>
    <p id="remindersDetail">Reminders description...</p>
</div>
```

-

```
<script>
$('.sideLinks').find('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $moreInfo = $('#moreInfo'),
        id = $(this).attr('href');
    $moreInfo.find('p').hide();
    $moreInfo.find(id).show();
});​
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Syon! This is exactly what I meant to describe earlier.

Comment: Seems odd but I have a unexpected token that keeps coming up in console. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Grab the code from the jsFiddle link. Maybe there was a problem copying from here.